# VSCode Dev container unable to connect to Postgresql using Mac M1

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, docker, fastapi, vscode-devcontainer

I'm using FastAPI, Python3.8, and PostgreSQL 10.7 to run my Application using VSCode and Dev Containers. Below is my sample docker-compose file

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: ./src
    depends_on:
    - db-setup
    restart: on-failure
    environment:
      HOST: 0.0.0.0
      PORT: "8084"
    entrypoint: ["/app/run.sh"]
    volumes:
    - ./src:/app
    ports:
    - 8084:8084

  db:
    image: postgres:10.7
    environment:
      PGDATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data1
    ports:
    - 5432:5432

  db-setup:
    build:
      context: ../api-db/setup
    command:
    - python3
    - main.py
    environment:
      ENV: local
    depends_on:
    - db
```

When I am running `docker-compose up` all went fine and I'm able to run the application successfully and able to access it from localhost as well and I'm able to connect to the PostgreSQL database as well.
Now the problem is with VSCode Dev Container. When I'm trying to run unittests from VSCode it is not able to connect to Postgresql.

> setup with "testcontainers.core.exceptions.TimeoutException: Wait time
> exceeded 120 sec.
> Method _connect, args () , kwargs {}.
> Exception (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to server: Connection refused    Is the server running on host
> "172.17.0.1" and accepting    TCP/IP connections on port 55576?
>
> (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)"
> @pytest.fixture(scope="session")
>
> > def db_session():
> >
> > ```
> >   postgres = PostgresContainer("postgres:10.7")
> >   postgres.start()
> > ```
>
> src/api/tests/conftest.py:52:
> _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _  /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/testcontainers/core/generic.py:47:
> in start
> self._connect()
>
> ---

I have tried changing ports from `5432:5432` to `80:5432` but it didn't work. Also, I can clearly see that my Postgresql container is up and running in the following VSCode screenshot.
Actually, this started to happen when I moved to my new Mac M1 and previously I was using an old Mac with an Intel chip. It might help in understanding the problem. I'm assuming no issues with my application since it's working fine locally and using docker using `docker-compose up` but the dev container seems to have issues connecting to Postgresql

[image]

Comment: "I'm able to connect to PostgreSQL database as well", from outside the container? Have you tried connecting to the database via a PGManager sort of tool?

Comment: Yes I am to run the application via localhost in the browser and are to make crud operations.So may be 127.0.0.1:5432 is working but I don't where the docker is try ing to connect PostgreSQL using 172.17.0.1: 55576

Comment: Being able to access the application via browser doesn't mean your db is also accessible. Your backend has access to it because they are both running in the same container. That seems to be your problem right there. You need to expose your database.

Comment: ©AndreFejio you might be correct but I don't know exactly how it can make any difference it was working fine with the same docker-compose in my Intel Mac

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error log:

> Connection refused Is the server running on host "172.17.0.1" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 55576?

But in your docker-compose, you specify the port of Postgres container to be 5432. Also check if the IP address 172.17.0.1 is what you wish. You should set the name of the host appropriately.